# Is there a way to show no status type for discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get my discord bot to not show "Playing" or "STREAMING" or "WATCHING"... etc

[Here is a example, Top User (wiggy) is what I want the bot to show. Bottom is what it currently shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cwee.png)

Is there a way to do this?
My current code:

```
client.user.setActivity("Status Here")
```

This still only shows "Playing Status Here"

Comment: You can try this code line to `null || blank` the activity `client.user.setActivity( { activity: null} )`

Comment: Nah, Didn't work. Also tried type instead of activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Bots cannot have a custom status unfortunately. Only users